# "Going above and beyond to assist" is this correct?

Tags: expressions, gratitude

I'm writing a thank you note to a colleague who came in from vacation to assist me.  Is this correct grammar:

> "Thank you for going above and beyond to assist in resolving the matter!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost.

[Above and beyond](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/above-and-beyond?q=above%20and%20beyond) has two meanings. [Oxford]

> 1. In excess of the expectations or demands of
> 2. In addition to

As you can see in the Oxford examples, the phrase can be used by itself in the second sense. However, in the first sense, it usually includes a second part. As in the Oxford example:

> She was always there to help us out in difficult times, above and beyond *the call of duty*

So, you might wanna modify your note accordingly

---

PS - If that doesn't work, you can say:

> Thank you for going out of your way to assist me.